# 2TB hard drive only showing as 4GB

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, nas

When I place the drive into an external enclosure, Linux Mint “Disks” application states that the drive is only 4GB, but it's a 2TB hard drive.

Disks also reports “Disk is OK, one bad sector.”

Any thoughts on data recovery, and why it things the drive is only 4GB?

The drives came out of my NAS when it became disfuctional.
 The drives are "Seagate Barracuda ST2000DM001 2TB 64MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive Bare Drive".
The drives have been working for about a year, but now my RAID 1 mirrored drives are both unreadable, with similar symptoms

Comment: Does the enclosure support 4TB disks?

Comment: Is the enclosure really old?

Comment: The hard drives are only 2TB, and the enclosure supports up to 3TB.

Comment: @ShaneDiDona nope, I bought it this week.

The same behaviour happened when I plugged directly into my motherboard.

Comment: @Psycogeek, I'll try and elaborate.  The drives came out of my NAS when it became disfuctional.  The drives are "Seagate Barracuda ST2000DM001 2TB 64MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive Bare Drive".

The drives have been working for about a year, but now my RAID 1 mirrored drives are both unreadable, with similar symptoms.

Comment: Oh, you know some raid setups MUST be un-raided, or un-inited in on the thing that set them up, or the act all weird in normal SATA ports. So that might be contributing to the problem. Some early blocks are turned special. They do this init to the disk so the device knows where they belong in an array, based on data on the disk itself, that way it can be moved around, and the thing knows where they belong. I dont know how it works, but it is possible it could be initied and un-inited on any other raid thing, or cleared of this data with manufacture tools.

Comment: Also chances are good that any data is still on them, and will remain on them until fully formatted (writes zeros) or full inited, which is also a clearing process. Some controllers having a quick and full init, and some controllerss only doing a quick init ever, even though you still get a warning that "all data will be erased" that isnt true until it is true because they zero out the whole drive, or when you do .

Comment: Thanks @Psycogeek, I'll try and unraid the drives using the DLINK 320 admin console.

Comment: @cjtightpant You need to provide the brand and model of the drive.  You want to recover data.  How did the data get on the drive?

Comment: The drives are "Seagate Barracuda ST2000DM001 2TB 64MB Cache SATA 6.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive Bare Drive". They were in a NAS, and yet then became unreadable in the exact same way.

Comment: I think this model of hdd is not good for NAS. I also have this Seagate ST2000DM001 and I used it for NAS storage. After a few months the hdd is failing, the NAS cannot read it. When I plugged it into my pc (ubuntu), the disk utility showed me that the hdd is only 4GB. Lucky me, I don't need to recover the files from it, because I used it for read only storage and I had the backups. I tried to format the disk but it was failed, I/O error. Better buy a new one, but not this model of hdd again.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the vast majority of commonly available external enclosures—unless specified otherwise—can only handle a single drive with a size of 2TB (max) or lower.

When I attempted to place a 3TB drive into a 2TB enclosure it would only show 800GB available.

> Any thoughts on data recovery…

If the drive has data on it already and you simply cannot read it via the external enclosure, no need to worry about data recovery. Chances are the enclosure itself is the issue. Meaning if you get an enclosure that can truly handle drives larger than 2TB you should be fine.

That said, many 2TB or higher enclosures are “weird” as in they operate on their own logic to access data to a connected drive. Meaning the trick of taking one SATA drive connected to a system one way and then hooking it up to an enclosure isn’t always guaranteed to work.

If the drive is new and just needs to be formatted, then don’t worry. Get an appropriate enclosure, stick the drive in and it should be good to go after a partitioning and formatting.

As far as the Linux aspect of this goes, on the offhand chance this is a system issue, then—as [explained on this site](http://carltonbale.com/how-to-break-the-2tb-2-terabyte-file-system-limit/)—you need to make sure the Linux kernel is 2.6.x or higher, the kernel must be compiled with CONFIG_LBD enabled and the drive should be partitioned with GPT (GUID partition tables) partition tables.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @JakeGould.  To remove the enclosure from the equation, I've plugged the drive directly into my motherboard, and the same problem occurs, unfortunately.  My primary concern at this point is to recover my data.  Hopefully ddrescue provides some results.